Kendo .showTooltip() for donut chart with multiple series
I am working with a jquery kendo chart configured as a donut that contains two series. I need to be able to programmatically highlight a section and show its tooltip in the second series, simulating the user hovering over a section of the chart. This is easy to do for the highlight, but I haven't found a clear solution for showing the tooltip when more than one series is involved.
Here is a bin to demonstrate what I'm trying to do:
https://dojo.telerik.com/EhEJaVaQ
Documentation for toggleHighlight (working - see the third example down for donut): https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/methods/togglehighlight
Documentation for showTooltip: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/methods/showtooltip
Thanks in advance!

Actually you got the correct documentation to get things done. To achieve the desired goal you can pass a function to showTooltip and using the point value and category determine which section to highlight. Here is a modified dojo that demonstrates this - https://dojo.telerik.com/@agpetrov/UjajuQaW/3

Thank you! Must have been missing something when I tried to implement it this way the first time

You can pass a function which will be called for each point, as demonstrated in the API:
chart.showTooltip(function(point) {
    return point.category === "C";
});

Here is the updated example
